# Is it possible to run TrueNAS on a docker?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I want to install **TrueNAS** on my **Ubuntu 20** without removing it. Is it possible to install **TrueNAS** on a **docker** container? 
Else, what solution could be better?

Comment: Install it in a virtual machine.

Comment: Performances will be bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found how to do it. But Samba on Ubuntu was an excellent alternative in my case.